# illegal argument exception in XPath

Tags: java, dom, xpath, illegalargumentexception

Whenever I run the below code, it gives me an Illegalargument exception if it find out the word, but if no matches, it will goes until end with no errors. can anybody help me to find out the solution?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {

   Parser p = new Parser();
   SAX2DOM sax2dom = null;
   org.w3c.dom.Node doc  = null;

   URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/users/1042952/mostafa");

   p.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
   p.setFeature(Parser.namespacePrefixesFeature, false);
   sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
   p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
   p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));
   doc = sax2dom.getDOM();

   final String term = "mostafa";
   String expression = "//*[contains(text(),$term)]";
   final QName termVariableName = new QName("term");
   class TermResolver implements XPathVariableResolver {
      @Override
      public Object resolveVariable(QName variableName) {
         return termVariableName.equals(variableName) ? term : null;
      }
   }
   javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(new TermResolver());
   Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, p, termVariableName);
   System.out.println("her is it"+node);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your immediate error is due to an illegal result type passed to `evaluate`. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29):

> If returnType is not one of the types defined in XPathConstants (
>   NUMBER, STRING, BOOLEAN, NODE or NODESET) then an
>   IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

2) The second argument to `evaluate` should be a context node, not the parser.

Use something like this:

```
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

**Note:** You probably meant to capitalize `Mostafa`.

Comment: what you mean by this? **Note: You probably meant to capitalize Mostafa.**

Comment: @user1064929 - The search string is case-sensitive.

Comment: oh i see, is there anyway to make it case-insensitive?

Comment: @user1064929 - Sort of. You could do this: `//*[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $term)]`